# Is this the correct way of iterating through users and check if they have a determined permission?

Tags: 7, users

I'm developing a module where I need to retrieve all users of a website and check if they have a specific permission.

```
<?php
$reviewers = array();

$result = db_query('SELECT uid, name FROM {users} ORDER BY uid');

while ($record = db_fetch_object($result)) {

    if ($record->uid != 0) {
        if (user_access('review article', user_load($record->uid), TRUE)) {

            $reviewers[$record->uid] = (string) $record->name . '@domain.com';

        }
    }   
}
```

I'm using this code and it works but it can become quite slow. I've tested in a site with 5.000 bogus users and it takes about 30 secs to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code works, but as you found out, it needs to load each user completely and is therefore very slow.

Unfortunately, the database schema of permissions/roles in D6 is really crappy. It stores all permissions of a role in a single role, separated with a comma.

But still, it should be possible to query that information directly. What you want to query is  which roles have a specific permission and then which users that have at least one of these roles.

Something like this:

```
db_query("SELECT u.uid, u.name FROM {users} u INNER JOIN {users_roles} ur ON u.uid = ur.uid INNER JOIN {permission} p ON p.rid = ur.rid WHERE p.perm LIKE '%s'", '%, $permission_name_here,%');
```

There are a few special cases where this doesn't work/needs additional checks:

- uid 1 does have all permissions
- all users automatically have the authenticated user role (rid 2) but that is not stored in the users_roles table. So if a permission could possibly be assigned to that role, then you need to explicitly check that and if yes, return all users.
- It is possible to dynamically assign roles to users based on some conditions. In this case, the query won't work for that...